# (MySql) Insert ou Update no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-update, sql-insert

Estou precisando realizar um ***Insert*** no banco de dados, caso não exista o cpf de uma pessoa. caso exista ela tem que fazer um ***Update***. Mas isso tudo através de um único script no **MySql**. Ilustrei o exemplo abaixo conforme estou realizando hoje:

1 Se o cpf da entidade (não é o código primário) não exista, então preciso executar conforme a SQL abaixo:

```
insert into entidade (cpf, nome, email) values (11111111111, 'robson', 'email')
```

2 Se o CPF existir, então vou apenas atualizar os dados, conforme a SQL abaixo:

```
update entidade set nome = 'robson', email = 'email' where cpf = 11111111111
```

Existe a possibilidade de isso ser uma única SQL ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name="A", age=19
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists